# bash: set the value from log as a variable

Tags: bash, variable, math

I have a log file consiste of 240 float digits in the following format:

```
5.4
5.1
5.2
5.4
5.4
4.9
5.0
5.2
5.5
5.3
5.6
5.4
5.1
5.3
5.3
5.1
5.2
..
4.8
```

Accesing to this log file in bash environment I need to compute mean value for this data (the sum of the elements devided by the number of elements) and then store the resulting value as a new variable that I am going to use inside the same bash script for some purposes
e.g. I need to store a variable mean = 5.0
Is it possible to do it directly in one bash script ?

Comment: The fact that the above reference doesn't answer this question *in its entirety* just shows that this question lacks focus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum/NR}' file.log
```

To store it in a bash variable use command substitution:

```
variable=$(awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum/NR}' file.log)
```

In order to change the precision you can use `printf`:

```
variable=$(awk '{sum+=$1}END{printf "%.1f", sum/NR}' file.log)
```